# numpy's tostring/fromstring --- what do I need to specify to restore the array

Tags: python, numpy, portability

Given a raw binary representation of a `numpy` array, what is the complete set of metadata needed to unambiguously restore the array?

For example,

```
>>> np.fromstring( np.array([42]).tostring())
array([  2.07507571e-322])
```

which is to be expected (with a hindsight, at least): here the I haven't told `fromstring` to expect ints, so it goes with the default float.

But it seems to me that just specifying the `dtype=np.float64` or similar may or may not be sufficient. For example,

```
>>> a = np.array([42.])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> a.dtype.byteorder
'='
```

which [the docs tell me](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html) means 'native order'. Meaning, it's going to be interpreted differently on a big-endian and little-endian machines --- or am I missing something simple?

Comment: sys.byteorder gives the endianness of the machine. It looks like you'd have to save this value too.

Comment: to save/load numpy array in a platform-independent way you could use [numpy.save/.load functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: For a single array, yes. In my case, I've 10 to a 100 thousand arrays, which I'm dumping to an sqlite db (along with other, non-array stuff). Besides, I'm just curious as to what it takes to be platform-independent :-).

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks, that's good to know! Mind making it an answer?

Comment: @Zhenya you can use `np.save` together with `StringIO`...

Comment: I don't know if your arrays are always 1d, if not you'll need to save the shape.

Comment: @Zhenya For several arrays you can use `np.savez` and `np.load`. To make sure you have all the needed metadata, see the npy format spec and implementation: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.txt https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.5.0/numpy/lib/format.py

Comment: @jorgeca: if you make this an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: unutbu was faster ;) I'm glad it helped!

Comment: @jorgeca: unutbu's answer's great, but --- your links are real eye-openers; they don't deserve being buried in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.byteorder` gives the endianness of the machine.

---

However, as @J.F.Sebastain, @seberg and @jorgeca have suggested, `np.savez` is a better way to go. The [help docstring shows](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html)

```
import io
content = io.BytesIO()
np.savez(content, x=x, y=y)
content.seek(0)
```

which means you could save the string `content` to an sqlite database.

Then, when you SELECT this string from the database, it can be re-converted into numpy arrays with

```
data = np.load(content)
```

Comment: Why do you use `tempfile` instead of `StringIO`?

Comment: @seberg: Yes, you are right -- thanks for the correction! A StringIO (or future compatibility, a BytesIO) would be better here.